# Load High quality image to imageview

Tags: android

I want to load a 15Mb image file into an imageview.. I tried loading it using piccasa and some other ways, But all return out of memory exception.

The code I used is

```
       Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.highqual).into(imageView);
```

Is there any way to make it possible in android

Comment: convert it to jpg n try....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

call this function `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filePath,int reqWidth, int reqHeight)`

which `reqHeight` and `reqWidth` is your `ImageView` dimension. also note that if it takes long time and send you `ANR` run it on a separate `thread` then set it to your `ImageView`.

the code is from doc that I changed it to read image file.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filePath,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    }
```

Reference:

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Am getting out of Memory Exception still

Comment: you can change `inSampleSize` to 4, try it I think it will work

Comment: did try my suggestion? I just want to know the result because it is very interesting for me.

Comment: Ya I tried following the reference, The image loaded even if it take too much time. But the quality of the image loaded is very low. Right now we are looking for some alternative way like reducing the image size with out quality loss

Comment: I tried this resolution: 800x480 for width and height! Works awsome.